# XCode vs VS2008 or how to work with a static library project on XCode

Tags: iphone, visual-studio-2008, xcode, static-libraries

I've working with Visual Studio for a long time and now I'm working with XCode.

On Visual Studio I can work with more than one project at the same time adding them to a solution (imagine a solutin with a windows application project and a library project).

Now I have XCode and two projects: an iPhone application and a static library. **Is there something similar to Visual Studio's solution on XCode?** If the answer is not, how can I link my iPhone application with the static library?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can indeed be very confusing how to use static libraries, i have written quite an extensive tutorial explaining how to create static libraries and how to use them in your projects (configuration) :

http://www.sodeso.nl/?p=822

Comment: It works! And now, How can I debug library code? I haven't found source files from library project?

Comment: Ok I've found it. Double click on library project file, to open another XCode IDE. And then, putting break points wherever I want.

Answer (score 1):

You just add the static library project itself to the iPhone project. When the iPhone project compiles, it will open and compile the static library project as well.

Comment: And how can I add a static library to the iPhone project?

Comment: @VansFannel: You do it the same way as you add source files or anything else - just drag to the project window or use the menu command `Project` => `Add to Project...`